# In libgit2, what do the git_index_entry->flags_extended mean (and when are they set)?

Tags: libgit2, objective-git

I am attempting to manage a repository's index vs. its HEAD tree using libgit2 (via Objective-Git, but I'm increasingly finding myself heading down the vanilla libgit2 rabbit hole), and am wondering what exactly the flags_extended field's bitmasks on git_index_entry struct actually mean. Additionally, when are these flags set? I've been digging through the libgit2 source, but cannot seem to find where flags_extended comes into play.

The reason I ask:

I have a simple test repository with one commit containing some simple test files. The working copy has one tracked file with a minor change and one untracked file, both of which have been staged externally (`git add .` on the commandline). In my application, I need to "unstage" the files, so I fetch their respective git_index_entry structs. I was expecting the flags_extended to have GIT_IDXENTRY_UPDATED set for the modified file and GIT_IDXENTRY_ADDED set for the previously untracked file, but in fact both flags_extended fields are empty, which is what prompted this question (the only thing set is the GIT_IDX_ENTRY_NAMEMASK in the flags field).

I can certainly fetch the HEAD tree and compare the entries with the entries in the index, but I was hoping that libgit2 was already providing that info via the flags_extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting the flags_extended to have GIT_IDXENTRY_UPDATED set for the modified file and GIT_IDXENTRY_ADDED set for the previously untracked file.

No, these flags are fundamentally internal to libgit2.  They are used to maintain the information about index entries in-memory after loading the index from disk.  They are to prevent and/or detect internal data races, they are *not* for determining the status of your repository.

If you want to compare the HEAD to the index, load the HEAD tree and then use [`git_diff_tree_to_index`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/diff.h#L780).

Comment: Thank you! I really wish this stuff was documented somewhere (although the documentation comment mentions these flags are not saved to disk, it has no indication about *where* exactly they're used). I will do a manual comparison to the HEAD!