# libgit2 equivalent of git reset?

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to get used to libgit2 and so am making simple git app. I know `git rm --cached <filepath>` is  removing the file from index (eg `git_index_remove_bypath(idx, path)`). Now am looking for `git reset <filepath>`

Does libgit2 have an example or some documentation on how to reset file to previous state aka unstage? The best explanation I found is [this one](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3632) but I really didn't get what he meant.

Any pointer or even example is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unstage a file you want to write the current HEAD commit entry for the file into the index with `git_index_add`. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048905/how-to-unstage-a-file-with-objective-git-libgit2) for some details.